# Ruby Compass error: `basename': no implicit conversion of Array into String)

Tags: ruby, sass, compass

I'm getting this error, when compiling sass:

```
(.../ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/image.rb:24:in `basename': no implicit conversion of Array into String)
```

My Config.rb is like this:

```
require 'bootstrap-sass'
require 'compass/import-once/activate'
# Require any additional compass plugins here.


# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
css_path = "C:/Development/Projects/SparNord.SparNordDotcom/SparNord.SparNordDotcom/css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
images_path = "C:/Development/Projects/SparNord.SparNordDotcom/SparNord.SparNordDotcom/images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
javascripts_path = "C:/Development/Projects/SparNord.SparNordDotcom/SparNord.SparNordDotcom/scripts"
cache_path = "C:/temp/sass/"

generated_images_path = "C:/Development/Projects/SparNord.SparNordDotcom/SparNord.SparNordDotcom/images/"

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors. Uncomment:
line_comments = false

# If you prefer the indented syntax, you might want to regenerate this
# project again passing --syntax sass, or you can uncomment this:
# preferred_syntax = :sass 
# and then run:
# sass-convert -R --from scss --to sass sass scss && rm -rf sass && mv scss sass
```

I've tried to uncomment relative_assets without any luck.

Any help is more than welcome :)

Comment: I know this is old, but I recently came across the same issue. If you're using a shell other than the basic Windows command prompt, try using the command prompt instead. You can also revert Ruby back to version 2.1.